# how to display language switch in magento 2 header

Tags: magento2

I want to display language switch in magento 2 header. Can any one help me?

Comment: check the site http://telecarsi.de/

Comment: not only one store with english language

Comment: @ Suresh Chikani  can you check that

Comment: but my client want to display germany and french in header

Comment: how i display in may header

Comment: please help job concern

Comment: You need to create multiple store views and assign a different language per store view to show language selection dropdown in the header.

Comment: i wait your answer

Comment: but my client  want to give the option to change the language frontend for customer

Comment: on single store